# Why don't impute function in R is not able to impute all NA values

Tags: r, missing-data

In my data set  I have around 40% missing values. So I used `impute()` from the `e1071` package. I used following code to impute missing values of integer variables by their median, and missing values for character variables by their mode.

```
library(mlr)
imp1 <- impute(obj = as.data.frame(train_prop), target=character(0), 
               classes = list(integer=imputeMedian(), factor=imputeMode()))
```

After executing the code I used following code to check missing value

```
table(is.na(imp1$data))
# FALSE    TRUE     
# 5493033   13742
```

Which is showing around 0.25% missing value

Before running the impute function I did same check and found the following result

```
# FALSE    TRUE 
# 3267515 2239260
```

Initially my data had 40% missing values, but after running `impute()` I'm getting 0.2% missing values.

Why don't I have 0% missing values?

Comment: From which package is `impute()`. There's no package called `ml`

Comment: @KenS. Package 'e1071' contains impute() function.

Comment: Could it be that some of your variables are neither integer variables nor character variables? If so, they will not be imputed and their missing values will remain.

Comment: You say that "missing value for character variable is by mode of that variable" but in your arguments you mention `factor` not `character`.

Comment: `e1071` has different [implementation](https://github.com/cran/e1071/blob/master/R/impute.R) of `impute`. @PythonLearner can you confirm which package are you using?

Comment: hey everyone, the `impute`function referred here belongs to [mlr package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mlr/versions/2.10/topics/impute)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming [impute](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mlr/versions/2.10/topics/impute) belongs to `mlr` package, just changing `classes` argument will solve the issue.

Note :

```
class(1)
[1] "numeric"
```

So, in `classes` argument, just change `integer` to `numeric`,

```
imp1 <- impute(obj = as.data.frame(train_prop), target =character(0),classes = list(numeric = imputeMedian(), factor = imputeMode()))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @parth.I will check it

Comment: no it is not working. Now I'm getting NA proportion close to 30%